# PHP scripts are not taking first variables correctly

Tags: php, html

First time poster so I apologize if I mess something up. I am a college student and for a previous assignment, I was given a couple of different prompts that needed to be coded into php and linked with an existing HTML file. This HTML file was provided by the professor, the only things I added were the PHP statements to link the scripts and the separation comments to help with readability:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Include jQuery library -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajaxbr/bs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>CS382 Summer 2023 Midterm Exam</title>
        <style>
            p, table {margin-left: 50px;}
            .datagrid { width: 400px;}
            .hrule { border-top: 1px solid #000}
            .listItem { padding: 6px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class='container-fluid'>
<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 1: Compute Net Income</h3>
                <?php
                    require("Problem1.php");
                ?>
            <form action="problem1.php" method="post">
                <table class='table table-bordered datagrid'>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for='income' >Gross Income:</label><input type='text' name="grossIncome" class='form-control' id="income" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for='dependents' >Number of Dependents: </label>
                            <select name="dependents" class="listItem" id="dependents">
                                <option value="0" >None</option>
                                <option value="1" >One</option>
                                <option value="2" >Two</option>
                                <option value="3" >Three</option>
                                <option value="4" >Four or more</option>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value="Display Net Income" class='btn btn-primary'>
                <input type='reset' class='btn btn-default'></p>
            </form>

            <hr class="hrule"></hr>
<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 2: Estimate Rental Charge</h3>
                <?php
                    require("Problem2.php");
                ?>
            <form action="problem2.php" method="post">
            <p>Select Vehicle Type:<br/>
                <input type='radio' name="category"  value='car' > Car<br/>
                <input type='radio' name="category"  value='suv'> SUV<br/>
                <input type='radio' name="category"  value='minivan'> Minivan<br/>
            </p>
                
            <p>Number of Days:  <input type='number' min="0" name="numDays" placeholder="Enter number of days" required/></p>
            <p><input type='checkbox' name='coverage' > Add collision damage coverage : $20 per day</p>

            <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value="Estimate Rental Charges" class='btn btn-primary'>
            <input type='reset' class='btn btn-default'></p>
            </form>


            <hr class="hrule"></hr>

<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 3: Display a list of Members (first name, last name, phone, member type) based on the selected member type(s) from the following list:</h3>
            <?php
                    require("Problem3.php");
                ?>    
            <form action="problem3.php" method="post">
                <p>Select member type:</p>
                <p>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Preferred' > Preferred<br/>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Regular' > Regular<br/>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Student' > Student<br/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Display Members</button>
                </p>
                </form>
            <hr class="hrule"></hr>
<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 4: Compute the number of containers needed to complete the order</h4>
            <?php
                    require("Problem4.php");
                ?>   
            <form method="post" action="problem4.php">
                <table class="table" style="width: 200px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Length:  </td>
                            <td><input type='number'  name="cartLength" placeholder="Enter the length of the container" required/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Height:  </td>
                            <td><input type='number'  name="cartHeight" placeholder="Enter the height of the container" required/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Distance:  </td>
                            <td><input type='number'  name="distance" placeholder="Enter the distance" required/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value="Estimate Transportation Charges" class='btn btn-primary'>
                    <input type='reset' class='btn btn-default'>
                </p>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I walked through the prompts I was able to get 1, 2, and 4 working, however now I am not able to get prompts 1 and 2 to run correctly anymore. The code does not seem to be passing the first variable correctly.

**Here is the prompt given and code I wrote for problem 1:**
Problem 1:
When a user enters gross income, selects the number of dependents from the drop-down menu, and presses the 'Display Net Income' button, send the data to a php file named problem1.php to process user input.
Output: Display an error message if the gross income is blank. Otherwise, display the gross income and taxes. Use the following tax rates to calculate taxes:

| Number of Dependents | Tax Rate |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 30% |
| 1 | 25% |
| 2 | 20% |
| 3 | 15% |
| 4+ | 10% |

```
<?php
    $grossIncome = $dependents = $taxRate = "";
    if (isset($_POST['grossIncome'])) {
        $grossIncome = $_POST["grossIncome"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['dependents'])) {
        $dependents = $_POST["dependents"];
    }
    if($grossIncome = ""){
        echo "Please enter a Gross Income amount.";
    }
    else{
        switch($dependents){
            case 0:
                $taxRate = .3;
                break;
            case 1:
                $taxRate = .25;
                break;
            case 2:
                $taxRate = .2;
                break;
            case 3:
                $taxRate = .15;
                break;
            default:
                $taxRate = .1;
                break;
        }
        $tax = intval($grossIncome) * $taxRate;
        echo "Gross Income: ".$grossIncome."<br>";
        echo "Number of Dependents: ".$dependents."<br>";
        echo "Tax Rate: ".($taxRate*100)."%<br>";
        echo "Tax Amount: $".$tax."<br>";
    }
?>
```

**And here is the prompt given and the code I wrote for Problem 2:**
Problem 2:

When a user selects a vehicle type using a radio button, enters the number of days, and presses the 'Estimate Rental Charges' button, send the data to a php file named problem2.php to process user input.

Output: calculate and display the rental charges using the following information:

| Vehicle Category | Rate per Day ($) |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 25 |
| SUV | 50 |
| Minivan | 70 |

If the Add collision damage coverage checkbox is checked, then add $20 per day to calculate the collision coverage and then add it to the total amount

Requirement: Your PHP script should display an error message if a vehicle type is not selected. Do not use the 'checked' property to select a default radio button.

```
<?php
    $category = $numDays = $coverage = "";
    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $category = $_POST["category"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['numDays'])) {
        $numDays = $_POST["numDays"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['coverage'])) {
        $coverage = $_POST["coverage"];
    }
    if($category = ""){
        echo "Please choose a vehicle type.";
    }
    $rentalCharges = 0;
    switch($category){
        case "car":
            $rentalCharges = 25 * intval($numDays);
            break;
        case "suv":
            $rentalCharges = 50 * intval($numDays);
            break;
        case "minivan":
            $rentalCharges = 70 * intval($numDays);
            break;
    }
    if($coverage){
        $rentalCharges += (20 * intval($numDays));
    }
    echo "Vehicle Type: ".$category."<br>";
    echo "Number of Days: ".$numDays."<br>";
    echo "Damage Coverage?: ";
        if($coverage){
            echo "Yes<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "No<br>";
        }
    echo "Total Rental Charge: $".$rentalCharges;
?>
```

I have also tried switching the require statements on the HTML doc to include statements and back again and commenting out the other three include/require statements to test each module.
This assignment is a past assignment, I am just trying to understand where I went wrong so I can learn from the mistake.

Comment: too many problems, please cut it down into bite-sized self-contained questions. if you havent takent a [tour] and learn [ask] please do so.

Comment: The only question I have is why my code is not taking the first variable correctly, the rest is just context.

Comment: What do you mean by "first variable?" Please be specific.

Comment: Sometimes there is such a thing as *too much* context - anyone trying to help you had to read through everything you've written to try to understand which bits are important. You can help people to help you by spending some extra time working out which are the important bits of context, and trying to come up with a [mre] that shows a specific problem. That's also a great skill to practice in general, because breaking problems down into smaller pieces is a big part of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in the PHP is a little skewed. Initially you are setting empty values for variables as placeholders before using `isset` to determine whether to assign a proper value to them. If these POST parameters remain empty the previously declared variables retain their empty value. Your code sort of works to that point but fails basically with a rookie error as you use a single `=` rather than `==` to test equality. A single `=` is used to SET the value whereas a double (or triple) `=` is used to test whether things are equal to some value - so rather than, for instance, `if($category = "")` that should be `if($category == "")`

That said you could refactor the PHP a little to make it more robust like this (incidentally I think that you should add a value to the HTML input element `name='coverage'` ~ say `value=1` )

The HTML (with value added)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Include jQuery library -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajaxbr/bs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>CS382 Summer 2023 Midterm Exam</title>
        <style>
            p, table {margin-left: 50px;}
            .datagrid { width: 400px;}
            .hrule { border-top: 1px solid #000}
            .listItem { padding: 6px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class='container-fluid'>
<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 1: Compute Net Income</h3>
                <?php
                    #require("Problem1.php");
                ?>
            <form action="problem1.php" method="post">
                <table class='table table-bordered datagrid'>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for='income' >Gross Income:</label><input type='text' name="grossIncome" class='form-control' id="income" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for='dependents' >Number of Dependents: </label>
                            <select name="dependents" class="listItem" id="dependents">
                                <option value="0" >None</option>
                                <option value="1" >One</option>
                                <option value="2" >Two</option>
                                <option value="3" >Three</option>
                                <option value="4" >Four or more</option>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value="Display Net Income" class='btn btn-primary'>
                <input type='reset' class='btn btn-default'></p>
            </form>

            <hr class="hrule"></hr>
<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 2: Estimate Rental Charge</h3>
                <?php
                    #require("Problem2.php");
                ?>
            <form action="problem2.php" method="post">
                <p>Select Vehicle Type:<br/>
                    <input type='radio' name="category"  value='car' > Car<br/>
                    <input type='radio' name="category"  value='suv'> SUV<br/>
                    <input type='radio' name="category"  value='minivan'> Minivan<br/>
                </p>
                    
                <p>Number of Days:  <input type='number' min="0" name="numDays" placeholder="Enter number of days" required/></p>
                <p><input type='checkbox' name='coverage' value=1 > Add collision damage coverage : $20 per day</p><!-- ############## Added a value!!!! ################ -->

                <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value="Estimate Rental Charges" class='btn btn-primary'>
                <input type='reset' class='btn btn-default'></p>
            </form>


            <hr class="hrule"></hr>

<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 3: Display a list of Members (first name, last name, phone, member type) based on the selected member type(s) from the following list:</h3>
            <?php
                    #require("Problem3.php");
                ?>    
            <form action="problem3.php" method="post">
                <p>Select member type:</p>
                <p>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Preferred' > Preferred<br/>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Regular' > Regular<br/>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='Student' > Student<br/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Display Members</button>
                </p>
                </form>
            <hr class="hrule"></hr>
<!--#######################################################################################################################################################-->
            <h3>Problem 4: Compute the number of containers needed to complete the order</h4>
            <?php
                    #require("Problem4.php");
                ?>   
            <form method="post" action="problem4.php">
                <table class="table" style="width: 200px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Length:  </td>
                            <td><input type='number'  name="cartLength" placeholder="Enter the length of the container" required/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Height:  </td>
                            <td><input type='number'  name="cartHeight" placeholder="Enter the height of the container" required/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Distance:  </td>
                            <td><input type='number'  name="distance" placeholder="Enter the distance" required/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value="Estimate Transportation Charges" class='btn btn-primary'>
                    <input type='reset' class='btn btn-default'>
                </p>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Problem 1**

```
<?php

    #problem 1
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( isset(
            $_POST['grossIncome'],
            $_POST['dependents']
        ) && !empty( $_POST['grossIncome'] ) ){
            $grossIncome = floatval( $_POST['grossIncome'] );
            $dependents = intval( $_POST['dependents'] );
            
            
            function getrate( $dependents ){
                switch( intval( $dependents ) ){
                    case 0:return 0.3;
                    case 1:return 0.25;
                    case 2:return 0.2;
                    case 3:return 0.15;
                    default:return 0.1;
                }
            }
            
            $rate=getrate( $dependents );
            
            printf('
                <div>Number of Dependents: %s</div>
                <div>Tax Rate:%s%%</div>
                <div>Tax Amount:$%s</div>
                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>',
                $dependents,
                ($rate/100),
                ($grossIncome * $rate)
            );
            
            
        }else{
            if( empty( $_POST['grossIncome'] ) )echo 'Please enter a Gross Income amount.<br /><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>';
        }
    }
?>
```

**Problem 2**

```
<?php

    # problem 2
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( isset(
            $_POST['category'],
            $_POST['numDays']
        ) && !empty( $_POST['category'] )){
            
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $numDays = intval( $_POST['numDays'] );
            /*
                Coverage cannot be tested in the above `isset` because it is optional
                hence testing here with ternary operator.
                
                A value was added to this HTML element to ensure that it shows in 
                POST array and is NOT empty if actually checked!
            */
            $coverage = isset( $_POST['coverage'] ) ? intval( $_POST['coverage'] ) : 0;
            
            function getcharges($cat,$days){
                switch( $cat ){
                    case 'car':return 25 * $days;
                    case 'suv':return 50 * $days;
                    case 'minivan':return 70 * $days;
                }
            }

            
            $rentalCharges = getcharges( $category, $numDays );
            $rentalCharges += $coverage ? ( $numDays * 20 ) : 0;
            
            
            printf(
                '
                <div>Vehicle Type: %s</div>
                <div>Number of Days: %s</div>
                <div>Damage Cover: %s</div>
                <div>Total Rental Charge: $%s</div>
                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>',
                $category,
                $numDays,
                $coverage ? 'Yes' : 'No',
                $rentalCharges
            );
            
            
            
        }else{
            if( empty( $_POST['category'] ) )echo 'Please choose a vehicle type!<br /><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This made a lot more sense!